# Help proving a short exact sequence

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, exact-sequence

> Show the following sequence is an exact sequence of $\mathbb Z$-modules when $n$ is a positive integer such that $n=rs$:
>   $$ 0 \to r\mathbb{Z}_n \to \mathbb{Z}_n \to s\mathbb{Z}_n \to 0. $$

should i attack this problem using the statement tha a short sequence is exact if and only if  $$ Ker(f)=Im(g) $$ which function should i consider for $f$ and $g$ ?

Comment: You can't prove that a sequence is exact until you know what the maps in the sequence are, so maybe you should think about that first.

Comment: what do you mean by $rZ_n$ ? is it $(Z_n)^r$  or $Z_{n/r}$ ?

Comment: $$ rZ_n = r(\mathbb Z /(n))$$

Comment: It seems to me that the "obvious" maps work just fine.

Comment: @mixedmath: I think so also.

Comment: yes the obvious maps work. My point was that the maps are obvious and the poser of the question should be able to work out the maps as soon as he realizes that he needs to know the definition of these maps before having a hope at answering this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are given the sequence
$$
0\to r\Bbb Z_n\xrightarrow{g}\Bbb Z_n\xrightarrow{f} s\Bbb Z_n\to 0\tag{1}
$$
where $n=rs$, $g(rx+n\Bbb Z)=rx+n\Bbb Z$, and $f(x+n\Bbb Z)=sx+n\Bbb Z$.

Note that
\begin{align*}
\DeclareMathOperator{im}{im}\im g
&= \{rx+n\Bbb Z:x\in\Bbb Z\} \\
&= \{x+n\Bbb Z:r\mid x\}
\end{align*}
Furthermore
\begin{align*}
\ker f
&= \{x+n\Bbb Z:\exists \ell\in\Bbb Z, sx=\ell n\} \\
&= \{x+n\Bbb Z:\exists\ell\in\Bbb Z,sx=\ell rs\} \\
&= \{x+n\Bbb Z:\exists\ell\in\Bbb Z,x=\ell r\} \\
&= \{x+n\Bbb Z:r\mid x\}
\end{align*}
Hence $\ker f=\im g$.

To see that $g$ is injective, note that
\begin{align*}
\ker g
&= \{rx+n\Bbb Z:\exists\ell\in\Bbb Z,rx=n\ell\} \\
&= \{rx+n\Bbb Z:\exists\ell\in\Bbb Z,rx=rs\ell\} \\
&= \{rx+n\Bbb Z:\exists\ell\in\Bbb Z,x=s\ell\} \\
&= \{rs\ell+n\Bbb Z:\ell\in\Bbb Z\} \\
&= \{n\ell+n\Bbb Z:\ell\in\Bbb Z\} \\
&\simeq 0
\end{align*}

To see that $f$ is surjective note that
\begin{align*}
\im f
&= \{sx+n\Bbb Z:x\in\Bbb Z\} \\
&= s\Bbb Z_n
\end{align*}
This proves that (1) is exact.

Comment: Maybe for completeness you could put a short note justifying $x=sl$ follows from $rx=rsl$ by using that $\mathbb Z$ is an integral domain?

Comment: @user99680 very funny

Comment: I just meant that this does not hold in "torsion rings" where one has zero divisors.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f:rZ_n\to Z_n$ and $g:Z_n\to sZ_n$

Take $f$ as a identity map and $g(x)=sx$ then you can easily see that $Image(f)=ker(g)$ and $g$ is onto.